# Get dimension of a DOMElement that was inserted using document.write

Tags: javascript, dom

A site makes a webservice call that returns HTML snippet. The site appends the response HTML to the document using document.write. Now if I want to figure out the dimension (width, height) of the element that got inserted just now, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: `var width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;var height = document.getElementById('foo').offsetHeight;`?

Comment: Using document.write seems ineffective, as you will overwrite the body if the page is already rendered? Perhaps [jQuery](http://jquery.com) could be of benefit for you, and `$(document.body).append($(newHtml))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using document.write your content in body will be replaced with the new content. I'm assuming only one element is placed in the body, so we get that element with `document.body.childNodes[0]`. If you add many elements, give them an id, or select them by tag or something else.

Every element in the DOM has a function called `getBoundingClientRect` which will give you an object with width and height properties.

```
var dimensions = document.body.childNodes[0].getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(dimensions);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: Anything in particular that I could help explain.